# Library for OAUTH2.0 provider with Django-nonrel on Google AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, django-nonrel, oauth2app

I'm developing an OAUTH 2.0 provider on Google App Engine with Django-nonrel. For authentication I have provided my own user authentication, so I'm not using Google Accounts.

I did some research about available OAUTH2.0 libraries for creating oauth providers. [oauth2app](http://hiidef.github.com/oauth2app/) looks quite promising, as it is also using Django.
Does anyone have experience with using this library on Google App Engine with Django-nonrel?
Or can anybody recommend a library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [oauth2app](http://hiidef.github.com/oauth2app/) and it only took me some minor changes in order to get in work with django-nonrel.

The only restriction is that the model classes in oauth2app use ManyToManyFields and this is not supported in django-nonrel, so I ended up changing them to ListFields. This then yields to some minor changes concerning the queries done in the library.

All in all oauth2app can be recommended also in combination with django-nonrel on Google App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this one

[oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2)

Oauth was unknown for me but this library help me a lot

The link has also examples to understand how it works

Comment: thanks a lot! But as far as I've seen oauth2 uses OAuth in version 1.0 and I want to use OAuth 2.0.